# Tapping into existing 3/4" supply and 3" drain to add washer

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc, pex

I understand there are a lot of variables to something like this, so I'm going to try to provide enough detail that people can at least understand the question here:

I have a washer/dryer I'd like to relocate to my garage. There is already a hot/cold PEX supply exposed in the garage, which runs up to supply one sink and one shower in a finished room (no other fixtures). There is also a 3" drain running from that room. Is it possible to tap into both the supply and drain lines with branches running along ceiling/wall and down to desired washer location as shown in the marked-up photo?

[image]

Comment: Supply lines on ceiling, yes. drain line, the **doors are in the way**. *Can you put a stack-able unit right next to the existing lines ?*

Comment: I was worried about that - I think I can fit a stacked unit, was just hoping there was a possibility of running drain line to the other wall, as that would give me space for a laundry sink.

Comment: Would you be willing to move that door?

Comment: some washer pumps might be able to lift it above the door. an intermediate basin and sump pump can lift it above the door for sure, at the cost of complication.